# Dataframe creation from text file and regex: python code optimisation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance

I want to extract patterns from a textfile and create pandas dataframe.

Each line inside the text file look like this:

```
2022-07-01,08:00:57.853, +12-34 = 1.11 (0. AA), a=0, b=1 cct= p=0 f=0 r=0 pb=0 pbb=0 prr=2569 du=89
```

I want to extract the following patterns:

```
+12-34, 1.11, a=0, b=1 cct= p=0 f=0 r=0 p=0 pbb=0 prr=2569 du=89 where cols={id,res,a,b,p,f,r,pb,pbb,prr,du}.
```

I have written the following the code to extract patterns and create dataframe. The file is around 500MB containing huge amount of rows.

```
files = glob.glob(path_torawfolder + "*.txt")

lines = []
for fle in files:
   with open(fle) as f:
      items = {}
      lines += f.readlines()


df = pd.DataFrame()
for l in lines:
  feature_interest = (l.split("+")[-1]).split("= ", 1)[-1]
  feature_dict = dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(\w+)', feature_interest))

  feature_dict["id"] = (l.split("+")[-1]).split(" =")[0]
  feature_dict["res"] = re.findall(r'(\d\.\d{2})',feature_interest)[0]


  dct = {k:[v] for k,v in feature_dict.items()}
  series = pd.DataFrame(dct)
  #print(series)
  df = pd.concat([df,series], ignore_index=True)
```

Any suggestions to optimize the code and reduce the processing time, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of improvement: in the previous code, there were few unnecessary conversions from dict to df.

```
dicts = []
def create_dataframe():
 df = pd.DataFrame()
 for l in lines:
    feature_interest = (l.split("+")[-1]).split("= ", 1)[-1]
    feature_dict = dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(\w+)', feature_interest))

    feature_dict["id"] = (l.split("+")[-1]).split(" =")[0]
    feature_dict["res"] = re.findall(r'(\d \.\d{2})',feature_interest)[0]
    dicts.append(feature_dict)
 
df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
return df
```

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
 8                                           def create_dataframe():
 9         1        551.0    551.0      0.0      df = pd.DataFrame()
10   1697339     727220.0      0.4      1.7      for l in lines:
11   1697338    1706328.0      1.0      4.0          feature_interest = (l.split("+")[-1]).split("= ", 1)[-1]
12   1697338   20857891.0     12.3     49.1          feature_dict = dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(\w+)', feature_interest))
13                                           
14   1697338    1987874.0      1.2      4.7          feature_dict["ctry_provider"] = (l.split("+")[-1]).split(" =")[0]
15   1697338    9142820.0      5.4     21.5          feature_dict["acpa_codes"] = re.findall(r'(\d\.\d{2})',feature_interest)[0]
16   1697338    1039880.0      0.6      2.4          dicts.append(feature_dict)
17                                                
18         1    7025303.0 7025303.0     16.5      df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
19         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      return df
```

Improvement reduced the computation to few mins. Any more suggestions to optimize by using dask or parallel computing?